# Print selected multiple item from tilelist in flex3

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, printing, actionscript, flex3

i'm working on flex 3 project. in which i have one tileList in which there are muliple images, every images put in different canvas in tileList. i will give **allowmultipleSelection** to true. now i need to print all that Images on print button click, which user select from TileList.

please give me proper suggestion, how i will DO.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer Here, I take Tile instead of TileList and i push all Selected Image into one Array. And in **printer.printPage** I will Pass that Array and It will work now.

```
 /* MyCustomItemBox */

  <mx:HBox  id="hb"  autoLayout="false">
    <mx:Image id="img" source="{imageURL}"/>
  </mx:HBox>


 /*   Print Script */

 // Custom Component which will be added in to Tile. 
 var myCustomBox= new MyCustomItemBox();
 thumbView.addChild(myCustomBox);

  // On Print Button Click
 protected function onPrintPages(event:MouseEvent):void
 {
    var printer:Printer = new Printer();
    var arr:Array = new Array();

        for(var i:int = 0;i<10;i++)
            {
                 var bdi:MyCustomItemBox = thumbView.getChildAt(i) as MyCustomItemBox;
                var hb:HBox = bdi.getChildByName("hb") as HBox;
                arr.push( hb.getChildByName( 'img' ) as UIComponent  );
            }

   if(arr.length > 0)
        printer.printPage(arr,null, "showAll");

 }

<mx:Tile id="thumbView" autoLayout="false" width="90%" height="90%" />
```